# Ionic2: ngOnChanges not triggering

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to perform some action whenever the input value or the slider is changed, but why is ngOnchanges not getting triggered when text or range input is changed?

Controller:

```
 export class APage implements OnChanges {

      @Input() total: string;
      @Input() percentage: string;

      constructor() {

      }

      ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
          console.log('ngOnChanges');
      }

    }
```

Template:

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item>      
        <ion-label floating>Total</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngmodel)]="total"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Percentage: {{percentage}} %</ion-label>
        <ion-range [(ngModel)]="percentage" min="0" max="100">
        </ion-range>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**Update1:**

Add @Input decorater as per the suggestion which didn't help.

**Update2:**

This works:

```
ion-range [(ngModel)]="percentage" min="0" max="100" (ionChange)="inputChanged()">
```

But it doesn't work for ion-input:

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngmodel)]="total" (ionChange)="inputChanged()"></ion-input>
```

**Update 3:**

It worked with keyup:

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngmodel)]="total" (keyup)="inputChanged()"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to decorate `aData` with `@Input()`

**Edit:**

It's probably that you need to hook into the ionic events via the template. If it's beta 8, the event is called `(ionChange)`, pre beta8 it's `(change)` , according to the [changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/2.0/CHANGELOG.md)

so something like `<ion-range [(ngModel)]="percentage" (ionChange)="changeFunc()" min="0" max="100">`

Comment: Have updated with code with @Input which didn't work

Comment: I'm using beta.8. ionChange worked for range but is not working for ion-input